# How to add a .h file to a flex definition in CMake

Tags: cmake, clion, flex-lexer

So I am trying to use flex in a project with Clion (because I'm on windows), which uses CMake but I cannot compile because my lexer.l file includes token.h
my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

find_package(FLEX)

FLEX_TARGET(MyScanner lexer.l ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lex.yy.c)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
add_executable(lexer token.h ${FLEX_MyScanner_OUTPUTS}
         printtoken.c lexan.h lexanl.c )
```

ERROR:

```
[ 16%] Building C object CMakeFiles/lexer.dir/lex.yy.c.o
lexan.l:36:10: fatal error: token.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/lexer.dir/build.make:74: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/lexer.dir/lex.yy.c.o' failed
```

How do I include the token.h?

Comment: I haven't used `flex` in some time. If `token.h` exists at the time `MyScanner` builds, can you use the optional [`COMPILE_FLAGS `](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindFLEX.html) argument with `FLEX_TARGET()` to pass an include directory (containing `token.h`) to `flex`?

Comment: the token.h is not generated, its part of the projects and imported in many places. token.h is located in the same folder as lexer.l.
flex does not have an include option anywhere i can find, they assume you will pass it as part of the file list. ex: "flex -f lexer.c token.h".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem Solved:

I had to add `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` to the `include_directories()` call for it to find the header file.